# OS X changes in com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist takes (Java Preferences) effect only after mac restart

Tags: java, xcode, macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

Quiet often I need to change values stored by java.util.prefs.Preferences manually. Thanks to this answer I found out where they are stored. But when I edit this plist file changes takes effect only after mac restart. I mean the applications ignores these changes until I restart my computer. Is there any way to change this without restart?

My code to change plist

```
plutil -convert xml1 /Users/<myuser>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist
nano /Users/<myuser>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist
plutil -convert binary1 #do something and save the file /Users/<myuser>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist
```

The same occurs when I edit this plist using xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `killall cfprefsd` in OS X 10.9+

https://manytricks.com/blog/?p=3049